# Laravel Search Query Pagination - page 2 returning error "localhost redirected too many times"

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-pagination

I have a search bar that allows users to search for other profiles, I'm using the 'simplePaginate' method to show one result per page (this is for testing purposes and will be a higher amount when working). The first page loads fine with the issue appearing when I click the 'next' button. The page takes a few seconds to try and load and is then returning a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS page.

I've tested for the bug in the Chrome and Safari web browsers and both return the same type of error. The Site is currently running on my localhost.

I haven't been able to debug the issue that much as I have similar function that filters posts by category and paginates the results which is working fine. Because of this it's making it hard for me to see any problems with my code. I'm currently thinking it may be something going wrong with the Laravel 5.7 Pagination system?

I have provided all of the code related to the issue.

Search Form (located on my navigation bar)

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('usersearch') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          @csrf
          <input class="search-bar" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
          <button class="search-btn" type="submit">
              <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
          </button>
</form>
```

Search Function Route

```
Route::any('/usersearch', 'UserController@searchUsers')->name('usersearch');
```

Search Function in Controller

```
    public function searchUsers(Request $request)
    {

      request()->validate([
        'search' => 'required',
      ]);

      $q = $request->input('search');

      $resultCount = Users::where('name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->count();
      $users = Users::where('name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->simplePaginate(1);
      $pagination = $users->appends(array('q' => $q));

      return view('search')->with('users', $users)->with('resultCount', $resultCount)->withQuery($q);
    }
```

Displaying Pagination in View

```
@if ($users->hasPages())
      <p class="small-header">More Results</p>
      {{$users->links()}}  
@endif
```

So I have two test accounts on the site with 'Fred' in the username the first account on page one displays with no problems, when clicking on the next button which should display page 2 with the second 'Fred' account it takes a while to load before displaying the too many redirects error page.

HTML Being Displayed from pagination links

```
<ul class="pagination" role="navigation">

  <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true">
    <span class="page-link">« Previous</span>
  </li>

  <li class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link" href="http://localhost:8888/projectboxnew/public/usersearch?q=Fred&page=2" rel="next">Next »</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you show html-code of pagination generated by `{{$users->links()}}` on page one?

Comment: @Petr Just Added it to the question for you, apologies for the slow response.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but maybe problem is caused by an absence of `search` parameter on second page (because form hasn't been submitted on page one). Try to get `q` from request somehow. And remove validation of `search`, because there isn't `search` on page two.

Comment: Removed the validation, and was able to access page two, however it was then losing the query and showing all users. changed the '$q' variable to '$search' to match the form fields name and everything is working as intended with validation added back in. Cheers for the help @Petr.